# Accessing Terraform variables outside the module

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-keyvault

I have a terraform folder structure like below. I am accessing an output variable from `01_app` module to the `02_tenant` module. However the output variable is not accessible across modules.

I am managing two different state files for these two folders. Can someone help me in accessing the output variables across modules.

[image]

I have declared a output variable in `01_app/main_infra_app.tf`:

```
output "key_vault_id" {
  value = "${azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id}"
}
```

`02_tenant/variables.tf`:

```
variable "key_vault_id" {
}
```

I have added below block in `02_tenant/main_infra_app.tf`:

```
module "kv" {
  source = "./01_app"
  key_vault_value_name  =   "${01_app.key_vault_id}"
}
```

**[EDIT: 01]**
This is the error log.

```
Terraform v0.12.9
2019-09-23T17:15:39.9624707Z [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\0.12.9\x64\terraform.exe init --backend-config=d:\a\r1\a/_Infrastructure/terraform/02_tenant/var/backend.tfvars --reconfigure
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0555160Z ‌There are some problems with the configuration, described below.‌
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0555674Z 
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0556565Z The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0556859Z Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.‌
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0557069Z ‌
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0557287Z ‌Error: ‌Extra characters after interpolation expression‌
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0557482Z 
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0557678Z ‌  on main_infra_tenant.tf line 42, in module &quot;x&quot;:‌
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0557881Z   42:   key_vault_value_name  =   &quot;${01‌_app‌.key_vault_id}&quot;‌
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0558082Z ‌
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0558277Z Expected a closing brace to end the interpolation expression, but found extra
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0558484Z characters.
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0558656Z ‌
2019-09-23T17:15:40.0696178Z ##[error]Terraform command 'init' failed with exit code '1'.:  Extra characters after interpolation expression
```

**[EDIT 2]**
I have added below block in 02_tenant/main_infra_tenant.tf. As I have naming KV and RG conventions, I am now able to fetch the kv_id in second .tf file.

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                = var.kv_name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
}

# Write to Azure KV 
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kv_secret_for_key" {
  name         =  var.key_name
  value        =  base64encode(random_string.generate_key.result)
  key_vault_id =  "${data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id}"

}
```

Comment: This should work as described, so we will need more information as to why it is not. Please create a MCVE for your problem.

Comment: What's the error message you're receiving?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have added the error log.

Comment: According to your error log, it points to your error position, could you please check the main_infra_tenat.tf line 42? If you want to use this value literally and not as an interpolation function, you can try to use double-escaped (double $) and then check if the issue still occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your current code is using the `key_vault_id` output from the `01_app` module as an input to initialize the module itself. You should instead use the `key_vault_id` output from `01_app` in another piece of infrastructure.

Try doing something like this instead to use `01_app`'s output variable `key_vault_id` in `02_tenant`:

In `02_tenant/main_infra_app.tf`:

```
module "kv" {
  source                =   "./01_app"
  key_vault_value_name  =   "somevalue"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test" {
  name         = "key-vault-name"
  key_vault_id = "${module.kv.key_vault_id}"
}
```

So now your code uses `01_app`'s output `key_vault_id` in the `02_tenant` module.

Comment: Thanks @Adil, I am able to fetch the kv.id in next .tf file